# Changing lock screen theme in Linux Mint KDE

Tags: linux-mint, kde, themes

How can I change the theme (or at least background picture) of a lock screen in Linux Mint 15 with KDE desktop? It is not consistent with log in screen and looks out of place. Nothing found in settings or online...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it by going into the folder with themes and replacing the default background image of default theme (keeping the name and dimensions). I understand there must be a better solution, but I'm not aware of any.

Comment: This was filed as a bug before this question at the start of 2013, was discussed including many workarounds, and was made configurable in Plasma 5. https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=312828